# Aurelia - how to register view resources for ViewCompiler?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, aurelia-templating

I have a row-based (table-like) custom element, which renders its template dynamically based on a bindable columns attribute. It composes the row template in string and uses *ViewCompiler*, *ViewFactory* and *View* to render.

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {bindable, ViewCompiler, ViewResources} from 'aurelia-templating';

@inject(ViewCompiler, ViewResources)
export class MyDynamicGrid {
    @bindable columns: any[];
    @bindable rows: any[];

    constructor(viewCompiler: ViewCompiler, viewResources: ViewResources) {
        const template = '<template><custom-element></custom-element></template>'; //this is rather complex in practice

        viewResources.registerElement('custom-element', /* HtmlBehaviorResource? */);
        this._viewFactory = viewCompiler.compile(template, viewResources);
    }

    _render() : void {
        const view = this._viewFactory.create(/* some container */);
        view.bind(someContext, someOverrideContext);
        //attach view to the DOM
    }
}
```

This works fine, until the custom template contains standard HTML elements. Once I start putting custom elements in the template, it stops working. It still renders the HTML, but the custom element's behaviour is not being attached by Aurelia.

I'm aware, that all custom elements should be "*registered*" in order to be used. "Normal registration" happens either in the view via `<require>`, or in the view-model `@viewResources`, or registering it globally.

In this particular case, however, the injected `ViewCompiler` only inherits the view resources of the view-model's parents. My question is: **how can be any additional view-resources registered?** I'm aware of the second parameter in `ViewCompiler`'s `compile` method, but couldn't make it work. The only way I was able to make it work, if I register it globally.

Note: this question is focusing on registering view resources. The dynamic rendering works just fine

Comment: What I'm looking for is, for example, how a custom element should be registered? I assume it has a string name for resolving and a view-model, optionally a template

Comment: Not duplicate of mentioned question, the dynamic view creatiion/rendering works just fine. However, I'd like to get an example of how a view resource should be registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution by diggin into the docs+github. I've created two samples for two different approaches:

1. Create `HtmlBehaviorResource` instance manually, this is to register one specific element.

Sample (based on: https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/blob/master/test/repeat-integration.spec.js)

```
import {CustomElement} from 'my-components/my-custom-element';
import {inject, Container} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {ViewCompiler, ViewResources} from 'aurelia-templating';
import {metadata} from 'aurelia-metadata';

@inject(ViewCompiler, ViewResources, Container)
export class MyDynamicGrid {

    //bindables and constructor is ommitted

    init(): void {
        const resource: HtmlBehaviorResource = metadata.get(metadata.resource, CustomElement);
        resource.initialize(this._container, CustomElement);
        resource.load(this._container, CustomElement)
            .then(() => {
                resource.register(this._viewResources);

                this._viewFactory = viewCompiler.compile(template, this._viewResources);
            });
    }
}
```

Remark: the line `resource.register(this._viewResources);` is equivalent to `this._viewResources.registerElement('custom-element', resource);`. The only difference is the first reads the name from convention or decorator.

2. Use `ViewEngine` and import (a) whole module(s). This is more appropriate if importing multiple resources, even different types (attribute, element, converter, etc.) and from different files.

Sample:

```
import {CustomElement} from 'my-components/my-custom-element';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {ViewCompiler, ViewResources, ViewEngine} from 'aurelia-templating';

@inject(ViewCompiler, ViewResources, ViewEngine)
export class MyDynamicGrid {

    //bindables and constructor is ommitted

    init(): void {
        this._viewEngine
            .importViewResources(['my-components/my-custom-element'], [undefined], this._viewResources)
            .then(() => {
                this._viewFactory = viewCompiler.compile(template, this._viewResources);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer works for me. As a next step, is there a way to import resources defined by <require> tags in the template itself?

Answer (score 0):

I've found your question while struggling with the same problem, but I think I managed to make it work with `resources` parameter of `compile`. Here is my setup:

I wrapped the compilation into a helper class:

```
@autoinject
export class ViewFactoryHelper {
    constructor(resources, viewCompiler, container, loader) {
    }

    compileTemplate(html, bindingContext) {
        let viewFactory = this.viewCompiler.compile(html, this.resources);
        let view = viewFactory.create(this.container);
        view.bind(bindingContext);
        return view;
    }
}
```

And then the client looks like this:

```
@autoinject
export class SomethingToCreateDynamicControls {
    constructor(viewFactoryHelper, myCustomConverter, anotherCustomConverter) {
        viewFactoryHelper.resources.registerValueConverter('myCustomConverter', myCustomConverter);
        viewFactoryHelper.resources.registerValueConverter('anotherCustomConverter', anotherCustomConverter);
    }

    makeControl(model) {
        let html = '...'; // HTML that uses those converters in normal way
        let compiledTemplate = this.viewFactoryHelper.compileTemplate(html, model);
        // ...
    }
}
```

UPDATE: So far I'm not able to call `registerElement` instead of `registerValueConverter` with desired effect, so my answer is probably not a good one yet. I'll keep trying...

Comment: Yes, the key point would be how to use `registerElement`.

I'm aware that `ViewResources` can be injected, I'm already doing it (I didn't think it is relevant, but put it into the sample anyway). But this `viewResources` would only contain resources (custom elements, attributes, converters, behaviours) from the outer context.

I need to register an element manually, an equivalent to a `<require>` inside the view template.

Comment: I posted this question in a hope that some Aurelia-member will answer it quickly. But since it didn't happen, I'll just dig into the docs/github to find out. Hopefully I'll be able to post an answer soon :)

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am also looking for a way to resolve <require tags in dynamically created views. Thanks